# Why do I get class-memaccess compile error with boost::atomic_shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, stdatomic

The code example producing the error is (https://godbolt.org/g/WWkTHr):

```
#include <boost/smart_ptr/atomic_shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::shared_ptr<int> tmp = boost::make_shared<int>();
    boost::atomic_shared_ptr<int> test(tmp);
}
```

The compile error with GCC 8.1 with -Werror=class-memaccess:

```
In file included from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_67_0/boost/smart_ptr/atomic_shared_ptr.hpp: In instantiation of 'boost::atomic_shared_ptr<T>::atomic_shared_ptr(boost::shared_ptr<X>) [with T = int]':
<source>:6:43:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_67_0/boost/smart_ptr/atomic_shared_ptr.hpp:84:20: error: 'void* memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)' writing to an object of type 'class boost::detail::spinlock' with no trivial copy-assignment [-Werror=class-memaccess]
         std::memcpy( &l_, &init, sizeof( init ) );
         ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_67_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/spinlock.hpp:47,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_67_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/spinlock_pool.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_67_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:36,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_67_0/boost/smart_ptr/atomic_shared_ptr.hpp:16,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_67_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/spinlock_std_atomic.hpp:27:7: note: 'class boost::detail::spinlock' declared here
 class spinlock
       ^~~~~~~~
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: Seems like an implementation bug, i.e. suppressed warning which is no longer working with G++ 8. Do you able to switch into std::shared_ptr< std::atomic<int*> >/std::make_shared ?

Comment: Off cause you always able to `boost::atomic_shared_ptr<int> test( boost::move(tmp) );`

Comment: Looks like Boost is using `memcpy` to modify the object-representation of a `spinlock` on purpose, but you enabled a gcc warning for that and used `-Werror`.  Boost's code may depend on implementation-specific behaviour, but presumably it checks with `#ifdef` or something.  It works properly if you don't tell gcc to treat it as an error, right?  It compiles.  That warning is part of `-Wall` with gcc8.1, so presumably Boost will do something about it soon.

Comment: In general, if you do not control your own installation of Boost (or any other package), you can use `-isystem /path/to/boost` instead of `-I /path/to/boost`. This tells GCC you do not control it and are therefore uninterested in seeing warnings about it.